# Why can't open 1060 port on debian?

Tags: iptables, port

In my os--debian, i want to open port 1060.

```
~# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1060 -j ACCEPT
```

Now to check it with `iptables -L -n`.

```
~# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:1060

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
```

To scan port with tool `nmap`.

```
~# nmap 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-26 23:02 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000080s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open domain
3306/tcp open mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.67 seconds
```

Why can't open the port 1060 on my debian?

Comment: you have to have a service listening on that port, try ```nc -lvp 1060``` and scan with ```nmap``` after

Comment: nc -lvp 1060
listening on [any] 1060 ...

Comment: nmap  127.0.0.1---->1060/tcp open  polestar

Comment: since you dont have a deny rule in my point of View, your rule is useless, i think as you pointed out there is already a deamon running and is blocking your port